# 18.04 Switch users stops working after a while

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, gdm, switch-user

After a reboot, I am generally able to switch users, and this works for a while. However, after some time the switch user option returns me to the password dialogue for the current user, and clicking the "Switch to another use" link on the password screen returns me to the password screen.

I need to change user without having to reboot to reset this functionality. How do I do that?

This from my auth.log

```
Jan 26 09:54:50 eclipse gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0) Jan 26 09:54:50 eclipse systemd-logind[1248]: New session c2 of user gdm. 
Jan 26 09:54:53 eclipse gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm Jan 26 09:54:53 eclipse systemd-logind[1248]: Removed session c2. 
Jan 26 09:54:58 eclipse gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0) Jan 26 09:54:58 eclipse systemd-logind[1248]: New session c3 of user gdm. Jan 26 09:55:00 eclipse gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm 
Jan 26 09:55:00 eclipse systemd-logind[1248]: Removed session c3.
Jan 26 09:55:09 eclipse gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
```

I tailed the syslog and saw this.

```
Jan 26 10:10:36 eclipse /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[31595]: #011ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
Jan 26 10:10:36 eclipse /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[31595]: (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
Jan 26 10:10:36 eclipse /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[31595]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
Jan 26 10:10:36 eclipse /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[31595]: (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
```

Answer (score 0):

gdm is flawed, quite sad they've not fixed this yet, but installing lightdm improves it :

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

This allows me to switch user, but on doing so I have to enter password twice, firstly at switch user screen which takes me back to the locked login screen